# Why is my approach of using the new Twitter API bad?

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I would like to be able to post a tweet to twitter in the name of my users, who want to share their posts on my website as a tweet too. I am using James Mallison's wonderful TwitterAPIExchange class and am trying to post on twitter using PHP. The class is found [here](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php).

I am trying to use it in the following way:

```
        /** Set access tokens here - see: https://dev.twitter.com/apps/ **/
        $settings = array(
            'oauth_access_token' => $core->getOauthAccessToken(),
            'oauth_access_token_secret' => $core->getOauthAccessTokenSecret(),
            'consumer_key' => $core->getTwitterConsumerKey(),
            'consumer_secret' => $core->getTwitterConsumerSecret()
        );            
        $url = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json';
        $requestMethod = 'POST';            
        $stripped_question = "See my reply to \"$stripped_question\"";
        $stripped_response = $stripped_response;
        $message = $stripped_question.$stripped_response;
        /*$postfields = array(
            'status' => rawurlencode(rawurlencode($message))
        );*/            
        $postfields = array(
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"),
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_URL => $core->getHomeUrl(),
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'status=' . rawurlencode(rawurlencode($status)),
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
        );
        /** Perform the request and echo the response **/
        $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);
        echo "<!--".var_dump($twitter->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
            ->setPostfields($postfields)
            ->performRequest())."-->";
```

However, something is wrong, I get the following error:

```
string(63) "{"errors":[{"message":"Could not authenticate you","code":32}]}"
```

So, my question is: How can I post a tweet to twitter in the name of a user of my website? Why is twitter unable to authenticate the user? I have checked the data and everything seems to be correct, so I believe the problem lies in the second code in my post. Thanks so much for any answer.

Comment: Hey Lajos, did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Some small checks

1. Did you regenerate the access token?
2. You got write permissions in the app?

The first one worked for me.

Comment: Access level is Read, write, and direct messages. I have re-created the access token. So your answer has some good suggestions, but unfortunately does not solve the problem in my case.